# Extend the user model (avatar)?

Tags: django

I want to extend my user model and add avatar(image) field.
I created new app - accounts and inside the models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def download_location_of_usrpic(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=download_location_of_usrpic,
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        height_field="height_field", 
        width_field="width_field"
    )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My admin.py

```
from accounts.models import Profile
admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Made makemigrations and migrate

I also have a GCBV

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'image', )
    template_name = 'my_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_account')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

But I dont see this field in admin and got the mistake in account

```
Exception Value:    
Unknown field(s) (image) specified for User
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Your `User` model is attached to the serializer but it's the `Profile` model that contains the image field. Try setting your field to `'user__image'` (note the model reference then model field separated by double underscore) instead of just 'image'. A good read for this can be found on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Comment: If I add 'user__image' to the view fields I will get the same problem. If I add it to the model (rename image) I will get accounts.Profile.user__image: (fields.E002) Field names must not contain "__".